# Impala/Hive - Sum up the amount for Adjustment code

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

I have an Impala table named REV having wire_code and amount for each wire code

```
+---------+------+
|wire_code| amt  |
+---------+------+
| abc     | 100  |
+---------+------+
| def     | 50   | 
+---------+------+
| ghi     | 250  |
+---------+------+
| jkl     | 300  |
+---------+------+
```

and the other table is FA which is having wire_code and Ajusted_wire_code.

```
+---------+------+
|wire_code|adj_wc|
+---------+------+
| abc     | def  |
+---------+------+
|  ghi    | jkl  |
+---------+------+
```

I need to adjust the amount of wire code which is available as adj_wc in FA table.
For example:

"abc" is there in FA table and its getting adjusted to "def" then my output should be - wire_code "def" is having amount of (abc+def) as below.
"abc" amount will remain same.

```
+---------+------+
|wire_code| amt  | 
+---------+------+
| abc     | 100  |  
+---------+------+
| def     | 150  |
+---------+------+
| ghi     | 250  |
+---------+------+
| jkl     | 550  |
+---------+------+
```

Please help in this query. 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two joins:

```
select r.wire_code, r.amt+coalesce(a.amt,0) as amt
  from REV r
       left outer join FA f on r.wire_code=f.adj_wc     --adjustments
       left outer join REV a on f.wire_code=a.wire_code --adjusted amount
;
```

Comment: This query worked on the dataset. Thank you so much !

Comment: I have tested this script on actual data set which has one more column "Reporting lines" - I have updated in question. When we have any reporting line which is not common in both the wire codes (wire_code and adj_wc) then it is getting filtered using this query.
Please help in updating this query to have such records as well.

Comment: @ASaraf  Please do not modify questions after accepting answers. Create one more question instead please. There are many reason for this. 1st - I not necessarily may know the answer on modified question. 2nd this is simply wasting of answerers time. Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted Revert your original question to the previous version+ create one more question. Look, I even would not answer your question if I new you will update it later

Comment: Apologies for editing the original question. I have reverted the changes to have the original version. Can you please help me with the change in this query for new column. I will post the new question.

Comment: Please help with the new question with updated details.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376463/how-to-find-the-sum-of-value-based-on-adjustments-in-impala-query