# How to find the sum of value based on Adjustments in Impala query

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

I have an Impala table named REV having wire_code, amount and Reporting line for each wire code.

```
+---------+------+----------------+
|wire_code| amt  | Reporting_line |
+---------+------+----------------+
| abc     | 100  | Database       |
+---------+------+----------------+
| abc     | 10   | Revenue        |
+---------+------+----------------+
| def     | 50   | Database       |
+---------+------+----------------+
| def     | 25   | Polland        |
+---------+------+----------------+
| ghi     | 250  | Cost           |
+---------+------+----------------+
| jkl     | 300  | Cost           |
+---------+------+----------------+

and the other table is FA which is having wire_code and Ajusted_wire_code    

    +---------+------+
    |wire_code|adj_wc|
    +---------+------+
    | abc     | def  |
    +---------+------+
    |  ghi    | jkl  |
    +---------+------+


I need to adjust the amount of wire code which is available as adj_wc in FA table.
For example:
```

"abc" is there in FA table and it's getting adjusted to "def" then my output should be - wire_code "def" is having the amount of (abc and def) as below and "abc" amount will remain same.

I am using the query provided below and it is removing the records which are not common in both the Wire code, for example, def with reporting line, Polland. and abc has one extra reporting line Revenue which needs to be added to def wire code as abc is moving to def.

abc is getting adjusted to def - reporting lines of def which are not there in abc will remain same and the common reporting lines will be adjusted.

```
  select r.wire_code, r.amt+coalesce(a.amt,0) as amt
      from REV r
           left outer join FA f on r.wire_code=f.adj_wc     --adjustments
           left outer join REV a on f.wire_code=a.wire_code --adjusted amount
         Where REP.REPORTING_LINE = REP1.REPORTING_LINE
    ;
```

Expected results:

```
+---------+------+----------------+
|wire_code| amt  | Reporting_line |
+---------+------+----------------+
| abc     | 100  | Database       |
+---------+------+----------------+
| abc     | 10   | Revenue        |
+---------+------+----------------+
| def     | 150  | Database       |
+---------+------+----------------+
| def     | 10   | Revenue        |
+---------+------+----------------+
| def     | 25   | Polland        |
+---------+------+----------------+
| ghi     | 250  | Cost           |
+---------+------+----------------+
| jkl     | 550  | Cost           |
+---------+------+----------------+
```

Comment: @leftjoin - Please help in this query.

Answer (score 0):

I think below query working in hive

Try in impala and let me know

```
create table rev
(
wire_code varchar(200),
amt   int,
reporting varchar(200)
);

insert into rev values ('abc',100,'Database');
insert into rev values ('abc',10,'Revenue');
insert into rev values ('def',50,'Database');
insert into rev values ('def',25,'Polland');
insert into rev values ('ghi',250,'cost');
insert into rev values ('jkl',300,'cost');

create table fa
(
wire_code varchar(200),
adj_wc varchar(200)
);

insert into fa values ('abc','def');
insert into fa values ('ghi','jkl');

select rev.wire_code,
case when rev.wire_code=adj_wc then sum(amt) over(partition by reporting)
else amt end as amt,reporting
from rev inner join fa 
on (rev.wire_code=fa.wire_code or rev.wire_code=fa.adj_wc)
order by 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This query is working in impala but it is not returning the record number 4 from expected output, where Reporting line "Revenue" is there in "abc" needs to be moved to "def". Revenue line needs to be added for "def"
Please help into this.

Comment: Is there any way we can find the reporting lines which are there in "abc" and not in "def" and add them to the final result using UNION.

Comment: I don't understand both of your questions

Comment: In the expected output I have a record (def, 10, Revenue) as abc is moving to def But its not coming in query output. I am getting only 6 records.

Comment: I haven't included that record in my test data.  That is why it is not coming

Comment: Please help in updating the query to handle above mentioned case - 
This record is not there in data. But needs to be generated as we have record (abc, 10, Revenue) and abc getting adjusted to def then the reporting line which is there in abc but not in def needs to be generated for def as well with same amount